# reverse gravity effects in swift iOS SK

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

As the title suggests, is their a way to reverse gravity in iOS? By this i mean intead of an object falling at a set velocity, it will rise?

I am using xCode and iOS SpriteKit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure - you can set the `gravity` property of your `physicsWorld` to a vector pointing up. For example,

`myScene.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, -1.0f);`

Comment: Absolutely what i was after! Perfect Job! Will accept answer in 6 minutes